# StyleCop and MultipleGenericInterfaces and CA1033

Tags: c#, events, stylecop, generic-interface

I have an interface `IBakeable<T>` which has an event `OnCooked`

A couple of data classes `Pie` and `Bread`

And I have a classes which implements `IBakeable<Pie>` and `IBakeable<Bread>`

In order to implement this I think I have to implement the interfaces explicitly

```
public class BaseHeatSource: IBakeable<Pie>, IBakeable<Bread>
{
    private event EventHandler OnPieCooked;
    event EventHandler IBakeable<Pie>.OnCooked
    {
        add {OnPieCooked+= value;}
        remove {OnPieCooked-= value;}
    }

    private event EventHandler OnBreadCooked;
    event EventHandler IBakeable<Bread>.OnCooked
    {
        add {OnBreadCooked+= value;}
        remove {OnBreadCooked-= value;}
    }
}
```

And the class is inherited

```
public class Oven: BaseHeatSource
{

}

public class Fire: BaseHeatSource
{

}
```

Now I get the equivalent of:

> CA1033    Interface methods should be callable by child types
>
> Make
>   'BaseHeatSource' sealed (a breaking change if this class has
>   previously shipped), implement the method non-explicitly, or implement
>   a new method that exposes the functionality of
>   'IBakeable.OnCooked.add(EventHandler)' and is visible to derived
>   classes.

[Msdn states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182153.aspx):

> If the derived type re-implements (explicitly) the inherited
>   interface method, the base implementation can no longer be accessed.
>   The call through the current instance reference will invoke the
>   derived implementation; this causes recursion and an eventual stack
>   overflow.

Note that adding

```
protected void AddOnBreadCookedHandler(EventHandler handler)
{
    this.OnBreadCooked += handler;
}
```

does not resolve the rule.

Do I have to suppress this rule? or is there a way of fixing it?

Comment: It is a bad code smell.  What are you going to do when the Oven is going to be used to bake cakes and bricks as well?  Add ever more interfaces and events?  The heat source is quite capable of firing the right event.  If somebody is interested in it being done with *something* then it needs its own event that shows what was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this via Composition...

Created an abstract `Bakeable<T>` class as

```
public abstract Bakeable<T> : IBakeable<T>
{
    event EventHandler OnCooked;

    public Cooked(object sender)
    {
        var handler = this.OnCooked;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(sender, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

Created an `IBakeable<Pie>` property which is the `Bakeable<Pie>` class

for firing the event called `BakeablePie.Cooked`;

for attaching to the event it simply became `oven.BakeablePie.OnCooked += customerWantsPie.Eat`

I'm really not sure how this helps me in regard to Hans' comment in order to cook more things I need to add more properties